# Form not updated after ajax call jsf 2 rich faces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2.2, ajax4jsf

I am using jsf 2.2.6 and richfaces 4.5.2. a4j : command link is present inside datatable.  there is also an actionl istener call and, on complete thereafter. both work fine for the first time, but when the same link is clicked for the second time my action listener doesn't get called and subsequently nothing works. code as below. tried giving the formname in render attribute for updating the form. but no change..

```
 <a4j:commandLink id="e" actionListener="#{controller.selectItem}" value="#{msg.action_edit}"
        render="#{parentId}:item_entry_form" eventsQueue="i"
immediate="true" ajaxSingle="true"
        onclick="ed();" oncomplete="cEd(#{rowIndex});">
        <f:param name="objectId" value="#{rowIndex}" />
        <f:param name="conversationId" value="#{conversation.id}" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
```

Comment: <h:commandLink id="e" actionListener="#{controller.selectItem}" value="#{msg.action_edit}"
 render="#{parentId}:item_entry_form" eventsQueue="i"
 ignoreDupResponses="true" immediate="true" ajaxSingle="true"
 onclick="ed();" oncomplete="cEd(#{rowIndex});">
 <f:param name="objectId" value="#{rowIndex}" />
 <f:param name="conversationId" value="#{conversation.id}" />
</h:commandLink>

Comment: any suggestions here pls?

Comment: A MCVE is more helpful than this. Although I sense that it has something to do with "conversation ID" which looks too much like a hack.

Comment: We are in this migration project and have only started with jsf for few weeks..can you please elaborate more on the issues with conversation id? I could see that the correct id is getting passed.

Comment: With a decent conversation scope implementation, you should not have the need to manually pass it. If you needed to do so, this indicates a problem elsewhere.

Comment: this piece of code works fine with jsf 1.2 and seam 2.1. it has stopped working post migration ( jsf 2.2.6 , seam 2.3 and richfaces 4.5). will check more on the conversation scope implementation.